# Trouble with pointers in parameters.. bubble sort in c

Tags: c, sorting

I'm having trouble with my bubble sort program.. i have it all done except I'm having issues  where my function calls my `swap()` function..  which then uses the input as parameters...

I have tried it many different ways, below is my most recent attempt.

I am required to leave the swap as a separate function.
------------------EDIT-----------------------------
With your suggestions, especially Haris and BLUEPIXY my code seems to be working..

Though it has some error and says it can't start(im assuming this has more to do with codeblocks as its been giving me issues)

to clarify its a system error not codeblocks error
No more error codes

Here is my code:

```
            #include <stdio.h>
            #define MAX 9


            //moved values up here so it would be declared before its used below
            int values[] = {7, 3, 9, 4, 6, 1, 2, 8, 5};

            //functions
            void printValues(){
                int i;
                printf ("{");
                for(i = 0;i < 9;i ++){//small for loop to iterate through each element in array
                    printf("%d ", values[i]);
                }//end for loop
                printf("}");
            } //end printValues

            void swap(int *x, int *y){
                int* temp;
                *temp = *x;
                *x = *y;
                *y = *temp;
            } //end swap function

            void sort(){
                int i;
                int j;
                for (i=0;i<9;i++){ // starts our loop; loops 9 times, one for each int, increments for each loop.
                    for (j=0;j<9-i-1;j++){//starts at max length minus 1 minus i's current pass
                        if (values[j] > values[j + 1]){
                            swap(&values[j] , &values[j+1]);
                        }//end if statement
                    }//end secondary for loop
                }//end main for loop
            } //end sort function

            //# list; 9 integers



            int main(){
              printf("Before: \n");
              printValues();
              sort();
              printf("After: \n");
              printValues();

              return(0);
            } // end main
```

Comment: The error messages are quite clear. What don't you understand?

Comment: Many problems. 1. The types of the parameters in `swap` are missing. 2. `temp` type is not declared. 3. You are passing integers to `swap`. These are passed by reference so any changes made within `swap` are lost as soon as the function exits. My guess is that you actually want to pass in a pointer to the values and within `swap` you need to dereference the pointers.

Comment: `void swap(int *x, int *y){
        int temp = *x;
        *x = *y;
        *y = temp;
  }` , then at caller side `swap(&values[j] , &values[j+1]);`

Comment: Thank you BLUEPIXY , i had tried it that way before except i forgot the & pointer

Comment: `int* temp;` should be `int temp;`

Comment: I rolled back the last edit. You aren't supposed to fix the code in a question. For one, that makes the answers irrelevant.

Comment: o crap i just did it again, i had assumed it was just a problem with my internet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems i could spot in your code..

> 1) Extra Semi-colon

```
void swap(*x, *y){
            temp = x;
            x = y;
            y = temp;
        }; //end swap function
     //  ^ Should not have a semi-colon there
```

Semi-colons are given in the end of function prototypes, which is also missing in your code. Same is the case in the other function.

> 2) Variable undefined

`temp` variable is undeclared in `swap()`. Do

```
int* temp;
```

> 3) Type of parameters in `swap()` function

Change your `swap()` funtion to

```
void swap(int* x,int* y)
```

> 4) You passing integers to the `swap()` function. Better to pass address of the variables to `swap()` and then swap using that. Like suggested by [BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/971127/bluepixy) in the comment.

Your function should be

```
void swap(int *x, int *y)
{
    int temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}
```

And, you should call it as,

```
swap(&values[j] , &values[j+1]);
```

Comment: The extra semi-colon is hardly relevant. There are far worse problems.

Comment: i had originally had it as u suggested in step 3, but it complains about me converting ints to int* or vice versa

Comment: @Cyrus Obviously, you are sending `int` to the `swap()` function and receiving it in `int*`.

Comment: lol i totally spaced the & pointer, i actually had tried my code tht way before minus the & can't believe i forgot  ty very much for ur help @Haris